# Erro ao acessar banco de dados C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

To fazendo um trabalho da facul, e comecei ele no trampo essa semana, ai chegou fim de semana coloquei o projeto no pendrive e exportei o banco de dados pelo MySqlWorkBench tbem, consegui importar o banco, mas ai quando o programa vai acessar me da um erro, que é o seguinte:

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

A senha do banco no meu serviço é diferente, mas eu já mudei para a senha que uso no banco aqui de casa e mesmo assim não funciona, segue a string  de conexão

```
_conexaoMySQL = "server=localhost; user id = root;password=1234;database=frota";
```

Algm sabe como proceder?

Answer (score 0):

Vai no console do MySql se conecte com o banco de dados e digite:

```
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
```

Procure pela linha 'localhost', 'root'.
Caso ela não esteja presente crie o usuário 'root'@'localhost' com a sua senha, vou assumir que a senha é `1234` como na pergunta:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

Então conceda todos os privilégios de DML ao usuário 'root'@'localhost', vou assumir que seu banco de dados tenha o nome `frota` como na pergunta:

```
GRANT ALL ON frota.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

Agora tente logar pelo c#.